# Disable Managed Google Play - Make app public again

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have an app listed in the play console, which access has been limited to an internal play store for years - everything worked fine.

[Play console - advanced settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmxXg.png)

Now the customer decided, the app should not be limited to internal users any more, but to be available publicly in the play store. I would like to avoid to package the app with new package name and signature as a new app.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmanaging-private-apps-in-admin-console-versus-google-play-console%2Cimportant-information-about-app-publishing indicates it should be possible to remove that access limitation.

> You might want to use Google Play Console if any of the following are
> true:
>
> You might want to make the app public someday. If you publish a
> private app through Play Console, you can later change its settings to
> make it a public app.

But I do not find the option to deactivate that limitation. The tab for "Managed Google Play" allows only to add/remove Organisations for access, but not make it freely public again.

Is this possible and when, how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Google may have changed the rules on Managed Google Play. I definitely used to be able to turn it off but I don't think you can any more. Either that, or the act of publishing a release under Managed Google Play removes the ability to turn it off and publish widely. [Source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139?hl=en&ref_topic=9496238#zippy=%2Callow-rd-party-developer-publishing%2Cpublish-to-your-own-organization)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where the application was published with Managed by Google Play option turned on. Later we didn't had any option to turn it off even after creating the new app as shown in the below screenshot

[image]

Since we were not able to figure out what was the issue. Later reached out to google play support. Playstore support guys escalated the request to their technical team and they deleted the existing application and made some config changes I believe. After that when we created the new app, option to managed by google was turned off

[image]

**I think the best option in this type of scenario is to reach out the google play support.**

Comment: I tried the same thing but they told to release the app with different package name. I didn't publish the changes and the app is still available in playstore. And we have many active downloads and the refused to delete the app also. Did you had active downloads at that time? Can you please help how we can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as you do.

I contacted Google Support and a Google Support agent told me to publish a new app with a different package name, which is very disappointing. Perhaps this person is wrong, but that is the answer I received from them.

[image: Google Support Screenshot]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: @StefanoSansone this does provide an answer to the question. The asker has a Managed Google Play app and wants it to be a regular public app instead, without having to create a new app with a separate app id. According to Google Support this is not possible and the asker will have to create a new app with a separate app id, if he wants the app to be accessible to the public.

Answer (score -1):

If you navigate to Setup -> Advanced Settings, click the Managed Google Play Tab, make sure to unselect all the organisations associated with it.

the "Turn Off" Radio button some become enabled, then save!

Comment: I have the same issue as OP and I tried what you suggested. However when I unselect the organisation I get an errormessage stating "Choose at least 1 organisation" and I can't save so I can't make it public.

Comment: Same for me too. Do you have any solution?

Comment: @GertDunon Did you find some solution about it?

Comment: @PepaZapletal Unfortunately no